# The specified option 'clr enabled' is not supported by Azure SQL Edge

Tags: sql-server, macos, apple-m1, sqlclr, azure-sql-edge

I'm a .NET developer and new to mac (m1 pro). I use docker and pull the ***azure-sql-edge*** image. When I try to create a table with a `geometry` column or insert a value in the `geometry` type column that was generated by code first solution, I encounter the error below:

> Common Language Runtime(CLR) is not enabled on this instance.

I tried to enable CLR by running `exec sp_configure 'clr enabled',1`, but encountered the error below:

> The specified option 'clr enabled' is not supported by this edition of
> SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.

What to do? Please help me.

Comment: Out of curiosity what tool are you using to query your db? I noticed `sqlcmd` isn't available on the ARM64 azure-sql-edge image.

Comment: I use vscode database extension

Answer (score 8):

CLR-based functionality — whether it be the instance-level "CLR Integration" option (which enables custom / user-created assemblies); data types `geometry`, `geography`, and `hierarchyid`; built-in functions such as `COMPRESS`, `DECOMPRESS`, `FORMAT`, `AT TIMEZONE`; or a few other features — are not available in Azure SQL Edge. There is no way around this (at least not at this time). If any of this functionality is required, then using Azure SQL Edge as a platform is not an option. (Yeah, it kinda sucks, but that's how it goes.)

P.S. The CLR-based data types and built-in functions are *not* controlled via `sp_configure 'clr enabled'`. If they are available on the platform, then they cannot be disabled (outside of enabling fiber-mode / lightweight pooling, which is not something anyone should do).

Comment: Oh, that's so bad. I hope the solution will be found soon.

Comment: Not unless the spatial types are reimplemented. SQL Server's relation to .NET is .... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for Mac Silicon users:

1. Install Docker Desktop if you haven't already
2. In settings -> general -> "Use Virtualization framework" should be checked
3. In settings -> features in development -> "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" should be checked
4. Instead of using the Azure-SQL-Edge image, use the SQL2019 image. ie. Run from terminal: `docker run --name SQLExpress2019 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`

NOTES:

- Change password to something else.
- Also could possibly try 2022 instead of 2019.
- Express Edition is optional.
- Docker will display an emulation warning, but it still works

Comment: Thank you, though I can't connect to Azure data studio

Comment: @EvidenceEkanem Make sure your connection in ADS has localhost as the server, and SQL Login as the authentication type. sa is the username and whatever password you used in the setup...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others in the SQL2019 image CLR is supported

1. Pull Command : docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
2. docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

If this run command doesn't work(it definitely should though) then:

Docker website -> Search 'Azure SQL Edge' -> 'Azure SQL Edge' official from Microsoft -> Here you will find the run command.

Copy the command and make a change in the command i.e towards the end 'mcr.microsoft......' must be mentioned, replace it with 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest'